# PHP7 debian apt-get

Tags: debian, php

How to install PHP 7 via apt-get ?

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
```

## command line

```
wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
apt-get install php7
```

## install

```
# apt-get install php7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php7` is not available in the repositories for Debian Jessie. This could be because `php7` is not yet considered stable. You would need to have Debian Sid (unstable) to install `php7` from the repositories.

If you still want `php` for Debian Jessie, you can install `php5` with `apt-get install php5`

If you have Debian Sid, you can install `php7` with `apt-get install php7.0`

If you *really* need `php7` on Debian Jessie, you can compile it from source.

Comment: how to install php7 with sid via apt-get? I already have installed php7 from source on another server, but want to install it with apt-get in production for a more convenient update in the furture

Comment: Have a look at this: http://serverfault.com/a/22418. Instead of testing, you will want unstable.

Comment: The problem of drinking particular packages from sid is that unwanted dependencies it might bring along.